# Delegate.CreateDelegate is unable to bind to static generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, static, delegates

I'm trying to use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` [[MSDN link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xw3bk13.aspx) to bind to a static generic method, but the binding fails.
Here is the PoC code:

```
public static class CreateDelegateTest {
    public static void Main() {
        Action actionMethod = CreateDelegateTest.GetActionDelegate();
        Action<int> intActionMethod = CreateDelegateTest.GetActionDelegate<int>();
        Func<int> intFunctionMethod = CreateDelegateTest.GetFunctionDelegate<int>();
    }

    public static Action GetActionDelegate() {
        return (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), typeof(CreateDelegateTest), "ActionMethod");
    }

    public static Action<T> GetActionDelegate<T>() {
        return (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), typeof(CreateDelegateTest), "GenericActionMethod");
    }

    public static Func<TResult> GetFunctionDelegate<TResult>() {
        return (Func<TResult>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TResult>), typeof(CreateDelegateTest), "GenericFunctionMethod");
    }

    public static void ActionMethod() { }

    public static void GenericActionMethod<T>(T arg) { }

    public static TResult GenericFunctionMethod<TResult>() {
        return default(TResult);
    }
}
```

The `actionMethod` is created properly, but the `intActionMethod` and `intFunctionMethod` creation throws.

**Why is `CreateDelegate` unable to bind to generic methods? How to bind to them?**

I've submitted the bug on Microsoft Connect [[link]](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775129/delegate-createdelegate-is-unable-to-bind-to-a-static-generic-function-method). If you think that this is a bug, vote for it, please.

**Update 2:** I was wrong thinking that binding to the non-function generic methods succeeds. It turned out that any generic method fails to bind.

Comment: It is not a bug.  You'd normally rely on the compiler's type inference to create an instance of the specific method that you want to call, the one that handles the specific type.  CreateDelegate() doesn't do this for you, you must help and explicitly create the method.  MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod() is required.

Comment: @HansPassant Turned out I was mistaken about binding working for the non-function generic methods. This actually happens with all generic methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (I couldn't get your version of `GetActionDelegate()` to work also):

```
public class CreateDelegateTest
{
    public static Func<TResult> GetFunctionDelegate<TResult>()
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(CreateDelegateTest).GetMethod("FunctionMethod")
                                                   .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TResult));
        return (Func<TResult>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TResult>), methodInfo);
    }

    public static Action<T> GetActionDelegate<T>()
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(CreateDelegateTest).GetMethod("ActionMethod")
                                                   .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
        return (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>), methodInfo);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why `CreateDelegate(Type, Type, string)` overload fails to do this, it is just implemented this way.

**Update:**

It is still possible to use same approach with any delegate type. Main idea is to find correct arguments for `MakeGenericMethod()` call. Quick example of how it can be done:

```
public static Delegate CreateDelegate(Type delegateType, Type objectType, string methodName)
{
    var delegateMethod      = delegateType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    var delegateReturn      = delegateMethod.ReturnType;
    var delegateParameters  = delegateMethod.GetParameters();
    var methods             = objectType.GetMethods();
    MethodInfo method = null;
    ParameterInfo[] methodParameters = null;
    Type methodReturn = null;
    // find correct method by argument count
    foreach(var methodInfo in methods)
    {
        if(methodInfo.Name != methodName)
        {
            continue;
        }
        methodParameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        methodReturn = methodInfo.ReturnType;
        if(methodParameters.Length != delegateParameters.Length)
        {
            continue;
        }
        method = methodInfo;
    }
    if(method == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Method not found");
    }
    if(method.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
    {
        var genericArguments    = method.GetGenericArguments();
        var genericParameters   = new Type[genericArguments.Length];

        int genericArgumentIndex = Array.IndexOf(genericArguments, methodReturn);
        if(genericArgumentIndex != -1)
        {
            genericParameters[genericArgumentIndex] = delegateReturn;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < methodParameters.Length; ++i)
        {
            var methodParameter = methodParameters[i];
            genericArgumentIndex = Array.IndexOf(genericArguments, methodParameter.ParameterType);
            if(genericArgumentIndex == -1) continue;
            genericParameters[genericArgumentIndex] = delegateParameters[i].ParameterType;
        }

        if(Array.IndexOf(genericParameters, null) != -1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to resolve some generic parameters.");
        }

        var concreteMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericParameters);
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, concreteMethod);
    }
    else
    {
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, method);
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** I have extremely simplified overloaded method resolution in this example - it relies on arguments count only.

**Note 2:** It is still possible to write a method which canot be wrapped in delegate this way, for example, `int Method<T>(string arg)` (anything that does not reference generic argument in argument list or as a return value, which is a bad practice anyway).

Comment: Sadly, I'm unable to fix my real problem this way. In my real situation I just have a `TDelegate` generic type parameter for which I want to find a static method. It wouldn't be so easy to extract the required information from it.

Comment: I don't think that I understand the purpose of your code (or at least I am sure that there should be some other way to do what you want), but it is still possible to slightly improve `CreateDelegate()` for generic methods. Answer updated.

Comment: The purpose of my code is exposing the "DynamicInvoke" type of handler (`Func<object[], object>`) as a normal strict-typed "Invoke" handler. For example, suppose I have some "DynamicInvoke" handler which I want to expose as a `EventHandler<MyEventArgs>`. I just write `var adapter = new DynamicInvokeAdapter<EventHandler<MyEventArgs>>(handler)` and now I can do `adapter.Invoke(sender, e)`. I can subscribe it to some event, for example. The posted code is more complex, since it uses some magic to statically cache delegate creation factories, so that reflection is only used once per delegate type.

Comment: Your code seem to be a good (although understandingly cumbersome)  `Delegate.CreateDelegate` replacement. I'll still wait a bit, if you don't mind. Maybe there is still a way to fix the `Delegate.CreateDelegate`.